# IOS, removing warning?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to remove a warning from this line:

```
UIViewController * appController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]     viewController];
```

The warning I get for this line of code is the following:
"instance method 'viewController' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Can someone help explain how I might remove this waning?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast your application delegate:

```
UIViewController * appController = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] viewController];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a cast to your delegate:

```
UIViewController * appController = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] viewController];
```

Comment: How can this be downvoted when it's the same as another, upvoted answer?

Comment: It's only part of the original code. You'll also notice that it doesn't include `UIViewController *.....`

Comment: You need to put the first `[`-bracket at the start. Now it'll give you a syntax-error.

Comment: You are casting what is returned from viewcontroller to the app delegate. Your cast should be within the first square bracket.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your `...AppDelegate` is called, so I'm using `DemoAppDelegate` here.

```
UIViewController *appController = [(DemoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] viewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

typecasting is noisy and can be dangerous. to work around this, i usually end up creating a simple class method. assuming the class is always intended to be used as the app delegate, you can write something like this:

```
// MONApplicationDelegate.h
@interface MONApplicationDelegate : NSObject < UIApplicationDelegate >

// ...

+ (MONApplicationDelegate *)sharedApplicationDelegate;
- (UIViewController *)viewController;

@end

// MONApplicationDelegate.m
@implementation MONApplicationDelegate

// ...

+ (MONApplicationDelegate *)sharedApplicationDelegate
{
    id ret = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (nil == ret) {
        assert(0 && "oops - app delegate has not been created yet");
        return nil;
    }
    if (![ret isKindOfClass:[MONApplicationDelegate class]]) {
        assert(0 && "invalid class type for shared application delegate");
        return nil;
    }
    else {
        return ret;
    }
}

@end

// in action
UIViewController * appController =
  [[MONApplicationDelegate sharedApplicationDelegate] viewController];

// which is shorter and safer to use, when compared to:
UIViewController * appController =
  [(MONApplicationDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] viewController];
```